# Distributed spawning of units

Tags: spawning

I have a collision detection implemented in my game. Now I have spawning of units in a class `Spawn`:

```
public class Spawn {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    private String team;

    private String meta;


    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public String getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(String meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public void spawn(AbstractActor actor) {
        actor.setPosition(new Point(x, y));

    }
}
```

and I call `spawn()` method for every unit. I have multiples spawns btw but that's not important.

However when a unit (`AbstractActor`) gets spawned, it's spawned on `x`, `y`. But when the second unit gets spawned it's spawned on the same location and none of these units can move (because of my collision detection implementation). `AbstractActor` has `Point getPosition()`, `void setPosition(Point position)`, `double getRadius()`, which are maybe required in calculation (`notice that I use radius so every unit has CircleCollider`).

How would you implement spawning on different places close to the `x` and `y`. For now maximum players are `5` for one spawn but mostly `3` will be used.

Btw `spawn()` gets called at the beginning for every player and then if player dies after some time he respawns so the `spawn()` function gets called then too.

Thank You in advance for your help.

Comment: Offset your spawn position if it collides.  Offset it by whatever you want, but at minimum of the (extentsOfSpawnedActor + extentsOfExistingActor).  Then check for collision again, and repeat if necessary

Comment: Do you know in advance how many you need to spawn, and do you spawn them all at once into a space that's guaranteed to be empty at the time? Or do you need to handle spawning "one more" when there might be an unknown number of units arranged arbitrarily in the spawning zone?